# Directional plots in Python and matplotlib and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

In the matplotlib, we just the throw the samples and it plots. Now, I want to the sample display an arrow pointing towards the direction of next sample. It is like directional plot used for drawing electro-magnetic fields. I have put it into a simple example below.

My code:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,np.nan,1,2,np.nan],'y':[9,8,7,6,5]})
plt.plot(dfx['x'],dfx['y'],'.')
plt.show()
```

Presentoutput:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Can we assume you know about [`quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver)?

Comment: @Mr.T No. I have never come across it. Thanks for info.

Comment: @Mr.T I got it working by `plt.quiver(dfx['x'],dfx['y'],dfx['x'].diff(),dfx['y'].diff())
plt.show()` Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suggest that you write and accept your own answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from `Mr. T` in above comments, I got to know about `quiver`. I tried a few things and found a simple way to answer.

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,np.nan,1,2,np.nan,3,4,5],'y':[9,8,7,6,5,4,10,12]})
plt.quiver(dfx['x'],dfx['y'],dfx['x'].diff(),dfx['y'].diff())
plt.scatter(dfx['x'],dfx['y'],color='r',s=5)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]